# c++: calling multi-argument constructor using operator =

Tags: c++, oop

i have this sample:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {

public:
    int x;
    A(int one) { x = one; }
    int getX() { return x; }
};

void main()
{
    A first(5);
    first = 10;
}
```

which in here the constructor is called in both lines of main.

but if we had more than one variable in the class, is it possible to call the constructor with the operator `=`?

like in here:

```cpp
class A {

public:
    int x,y;
    A(int one,int sec) { x = one; y=sec;}
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
};
```

and create a class variable using `=` like this?

```cpp
A example=(50,40)
```

Comment: can't understand what you want to know, but for the last piece of code, you have to remove the = and just use `A example(50,40)` or `A example= A(50,40)`

Comment: so far as I know the answer is no. You need to define a pair and add a constructor that takes a pair as argument.

Comment: You can look this [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since C++11 you can do it with copy-list-initialization like this:

```
A example = {50, 40};
example = {40, 50};
```